# Kafka Based Pub/Sub with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

I am trying to develop a Pub/Sub system with Apache Kafka. The Rest API are written in NodeJS. The library I am using is [No-Kafka](https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-kafka). The user passes in the topic and offset (starting location) of the queue that he wants to consume from and the API returns the first 10 messages.

```
consumer.init().then(function() {
  console.log("Consumer Ready");
});
app.get('/:topic/:off', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.params.off);
consumer.subscribe(req.params.topic, 0, {
  offset: req.params.off
},
function(messageSet, topic, partition) {
  var msg = "";
  messageSet.some(function(m) {
    msg += m.message.value.toString('utf8') + " ";
    if (parseInt(m.offset, 10) > parseInt(req.params.off, 10) + 10) {
      res.send("Results: " + req.params.off + "  " + msg);
      return true;
    }
  });
});
});
```

I am using [Hurl-it](http://www.hurl.it) to make HTTP requests online. Whenever I make a request, it takes anywhere between 450 to 2000 ms. Is this a good response time? If no, how can I improve the speed of API?

Let me know if you need other information.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My code with Kafka-node.

```
var Consumer = new kafka.Consumer;
var client1 = new kafka.Client;
var consumer = new Consumer(client1, [{
    topic: 'TutorialTopic',
    partition: 0,
    offset: 0
}], {
    autoCommit: true,
    fromOffset: true
});


app.get('/consume/:off', function(req, res) {
    console.log("In Consume");

    consumer.setOffset('TutorialTopic', 0, req.params.off);
    consumer.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log("Consumer Ready");
        console.log(message);
    });

    res.send("Consumed");

});
```

Since the library provides an "on" event handler, how can I identify when two or more people access my website simultaneously? What is the best way to use kafka-node to access the messages from a particular offset?

Comment: No this is not a good response time. I use `kafka-node`, and I use Kafka to process all web requests. My Node `https` server does no processing on its own. It just publishes the request to Kafka. Other processes consume the messages and process them, writing the response back to Kafka. Node picks this up and spits it back to the web browser. The entire flow, from browser to node to kafka to consumer back to kafka back to node back to browser takes around 20 milliseconds.

Comment: And about 20% of that (or 4 milliseconds) is because of the speed of light and the distance between my browser and my servers. (Every 300 kilometers data has to travel adds 1 millisecond to the trip.)

Comment: Thanks David...Currently, my Kafka and the website is on the same server. But can you help me identify the issues in my code? I just want to consume 10 messages from an offset point provided by the user.

Comment: @DavidGriffin  It will be really helpful for me if you can post a sample code which takes the parameters such as kafka-topic and offset and reads around 10 messages from that offset. I am confused about how to approach the problem. I have also edited my question to show my effort. Thanks!